# Android places api implementation doesn't return results

Tags: android, google-places-api

I implemented places api in my app using the regular autocomplete edittext by [following this tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-api-example/) but no search result is being returned when I enter a text to the edittext on my phone. Neither an exception is thrown nor do I get search results. I have enabled the places api in the developer console and tried both server and android api keys. Can someone point me to the problem? 
Upon debugging I learned that the textview is taking that first 2 letters and passing it to the array adapter class and returns nothing. How can I change this behavior?

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY-API-KEY-HERE" />

public static ArrayList autocomplete(String input) {
        ArrayList resultList = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&components=country:us");
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            //Error processing Places API URL
            Log.e("TAG", mue.toString());
            mue.printStackTrace();
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            //Error cannecting to Places API
            Log.e("TAG", ioe.toString());
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                //System.out.println(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                //System.out.println("============================================================");
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            //cannot process JSON results
            Log.e("TAG", je.toString());
            je.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception exe){
            Log.e("TAG", exe.toString());
            exe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultList;
    }
```

this the autocomplete textview in the xml file.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:completionThreshold="5"/>
```

Comment: cannot help without looking at what you've tried. post your code.

Comment: I have added the relevant code snippets.

Comment: What's the response you get back?  It likely has an error status and message in the JSON response, but your code is ignoring the `status` and `error_message` JSON fields.

Comment: @spiv I didn't get none of those. It is very strange but I solved sorry that I haven't posted the answer. Turns out Google has a bug; I simply generated a new api key and all is working like a charm. But now I couldn't get the selected item latitude and longitude. Do you know how to get that?

Comment: You can get the location by fetching the details using the `place_id` of the prediction: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Google didn't like my old api key which was working fine with other parts of my code. I generated a new api key and it all works.